# how to pass a structure vector to a function in C++?

Tags: c++, oop

In the below example code I need to pass the structure vector to a function.

```
class A {
public:
    struct mystruct {   
        mystruct (int _label, double _dist) : label(_label), dist(_dist) {}   
        int label;
        double dist;
    };
}
```

I declared the vector as below:

```
 vector<A:: mystruct > mystry;
```

Now in this class "A" there is a function as below.

```
  myfunc ( vector<mystruct> &mystry );
```

How to pass the structure vector to my "myfunc"?

Comment: @nommyravian That question is about passing a vector and in my case its structure vector?

Comment: That's the thing about vectors. It doesn't matter what they contain.

Comment: Where are you having problems? Passing a vector to a function is like passing anything else to a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    struct mystruct {   
        mystruct (int _label, double _dist) : label(_label), dist(_dist) {}   
        int label;
        double dist;
    };

    void myfunc ( vector<mystruct> &mystry ){
        cout << mystry[0].label <<endl;
        cout << mystry[0].dist <<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A::mystruct temp_mystruct(5,2.5); \\create instance of struct.

    vector<A:: mystruct > mystry; \\ create vector of struct 
    mystry.push_back(temp_mystruct); \\ add struct instance to vector

    A a; \\ create instance of the class
    a.myfunc(mystry); \\call function
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This seems excessively complicated. The OP only asked how to pass the vector to `myfunc`.

Comment: @MichaelDorst - 1. This is a working example so OP can debug and get the idea. 2. I commented the impotent points that OP need to understand and make the program understandable. 3. I don't see any complected in this simple program that mostly copied from OPs code. =)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first you need to create an instance of `A`, like so:

```
A a;
```

Then, you need to call `myfunc` on `a`, passing it the value `mystry`.

```
a.myfunc(mystry);
```